# Bluetoothキーボードの Del キーを押すと Debian がシャットダウンしてしまう

Tags: linux, debian, key-mapping, key-binding

サンワサプライの [BTキーボード SKB-BT28BK](https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B07BSWN5NP/) をDebian 10で使おうとしたのですけども、deleteキーの上にあるDelキーを押すとパソコンの電源が切れてしまいます。
どうすればDelキーを押しても電源が切れないのでしょうか？

ちなみに、US配列で、iOSとMacに対応していますが、使っているパソコンはThinkCentreです。

Comment: 実物がないので何とも言えませんが、そのキーボードは `Del` キーで Ctrl-Alt-Delete キーシーケンスを送出するのかもしれません。Debian10 は systemd でしょうから、`sudo systemctl mask ctrl-alt-del.target` を実行すれば無効化できるかもしれません。

Comment: @metropolis 様　無効化できませんでしたね。

Comment: この[取扱説明書](https://www.sanwa.co.jp/support/setsumeisyo/pdf/S/SKB-BT28BK.pdf)では「ショートカットキー（iOSでのみ動作します）」「ロック 押すとロック画面を表示します。」となっています。販売元にどんなキーコードが通知されるのか聞いてみては？ それから、ubuntuですがこの辺の記事が関係するかも？[How to change mapping for the «PowerOff» key on keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/q/580902), [How to disable sleep / suspend / hibernate HP keyboard buttons for Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1103856)

Comment: @kunif 様　結局新しいキーボードを購入しました。

Comment: お二人ともありがとうございました！